# Timeout Expired while executing procedure in dataaccesslayer

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

When I am trying to execute the insert procedure,I am geeting the following in data accesslayer.Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
Plaese give me a solution

Comment: You haven't given us pretty much any information at all. In any case, the most likely issue is that you haven't configured your connection string right, or you forgot to pass it to your connection. A firewall blocking the communication is a typical problem in remote databases as well.

Comment: `Plaese give me a solution` . Can you please tell us what you have tried so far in google/code? `Give us code you tried` :)

Comment: Increase SQL commandTimeout propoerty, ScriptTimeout in page or HttpRunTime in web.config

Comment: in my dataaccesslayer while i am insering data to table,at d same time i am getting the count of columns from database in dataaccesslayer,and updating to table based on count id.But the error is coming as timeout expired.

Comment: I have increased the timeout propertyto 500 but still getting same error

Comment: You should put a bigger number like 16000...

Answer (score 0):

While it's possible that you have an extremely long INSERT statement that takes multiple seconds to execute, what seems more likely (especially as you tried increasing the timeout property) is that some other transaction has locked the table you are trying to insert into.

There are dozens of ways you could get into that situation.  If this doesn't usually happen, investigate whether someone else could be locking that table. It could be as simple as another developer leaving open a debugging session stopped at a breakpoint while he or she went to lunch.

If this is happening over and over again, every time you run, and there's no lock on the table that you can detect, it's possible that you're conflicting with yourself at runtime:  opening a transaction, changing something, and while the transaction is still open, executing a new command against the same database affecting one of the tables affected by the transaction.

If that's the case, you can do a couple of things:  re-design how you're doing this two-step process so you only need one connection open at a time, or try doing both activities in the same transaction.

Also, be sure you are doing proper housekeeping with SqlConnection, SqlTransaction, and SqlDataReader objects:  close or dispose of them as soon as you can.  You might look up the C# `using` statement if you are not familiar with it.